# convolutional AE on MNIST data set

Tags: machine-learning, testing, conv-neural-network, training-data, mnist

as part of a project, i need to build a convolutional AE and explore the change in train and test lost as a function of the latent space dimentions .
This is my code :

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader


batch_size = 128
learning_rate = 0.001
num_epochs = 15
latent_dim = 10,
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu") # Define the device

transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor()])

train_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=True, transform=transform, download=True)
test_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=False, transform=transform, download=True)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(64*7*7, latent_dim)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.fc(x)
        return x

class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(latent_dim, 64*7*7)
        self.conv1 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1)
        self.conv3 = nn.ConvTranspose2d(16, 1, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), 64, 7, 7)
        x = torch.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = self.sigmoid(self.conv3(x))
        return x

class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = Encoder(latent_dim)
        self.decoder = Decoder(latent_dim)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x
autoencoder=Autoencoder(10)

criterion = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(autoencoder.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
def train_and_evaluate(latent_dim):
    # Define the autoencoder model
    autoencoder = Autoencoder(latent_dim)
    autoencoder.to(device)

    # Define the loss function and optimizer
    criterion = nn.BCELoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(autoencoder.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

    # Train the autoencoder model
    train_losses = []
    running_train_loss = 0
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for data in train_loader:
            img, _ = data
            img = img.to(device)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            output = autoencoder(img)
            loss = criterion(output, img)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            train_losses.append(loss.item())
            running_train_loss += loss.item()

        print("Epoch [{}/{}], Train Loss: {:.4f}".format(epoch+1, num_epochs, running_train_loss / len(train_loader)))
        running_train_loss = 0

    # Evaluate the autoencoder model on the test set
    autoencoder.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        test_loss = 0
        test_losses = []
        for data in test_loader:
            img, _ = data
            img = img.to(device)
            output = autoencoder(img)
            loss = criterion(output, img)
            test_loss += loss.item() * img.size(0)
            test_losses.append(loss.item())

        test_loss /= len(test_loader.dataset)
        print("Latent dim: {}, Test Loss: {:.4f}".format(latent_dim, test_loss))

    return train_losses, test_losses
latent_dims = [5, 10, 15,20,25]

train_losses_all = []
test_losses_all = []
final_train_losses = []
final_test_losses = []

for latent_dim in latent_dims:
    train_losses, test_losses = train_and_evaluate(latent_dim)
    train_losses_all.append(train_losses)
    test_losses_all.append(test_losses)
    final_train_losses.append(train_losses[-1])
    final_test_losses.append(test_losses[-1])

plt.plot(latent_dims, final_train_losses, label="Final Train Loss")
plt.plot(latent_dims, final_test_losses, label="Final Test Loss")
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("Latent Dimension")
plt.ylabel("Loss")
plt.show()
```

here are my results :

```
Epoch [1/15], Train Loss: 0.2304
Epoch [2/15], Train Loss: 0.1610
Epoch [3/15], Train Loss: 0.1553
Epoch [4/15], Train Loss: 0.1511
Epoch [5/15], Train Loss: 0.1472
Epoch [6/15], Train Loss: 0.1446
Epoch [7/15], Train Loss: 0.1429
Epoch [8/15], Train Loss: 0.1416
Epoch [9/15], Train Loss: 0.1405
Epoch [10/15], Train Loss: 0.1397
Epoch [11/15], Train Loss: 0.1389
Epoch [12/15], Train Loss: 0.1383
Epoch [13/15], Train Loss: 0.1377
Epoch [14/15], Train Loss: 0.1372
Epoch [15/15], Train Loss: 0.1367
Latent dim: 5, Test Loss: 0.1366
Epoch [1/15], Train Loss: 0.2009
Epoch [2/15], Train Loss: 0.1242
Epoch [3/15], Train Loss: 0.1169
Epoch [4/15], Train Loss: 0.1130
Epoch [5/15], Train Loss: 0.1107
Epoch [6/15], Train Loss: 0.1089
Epoch [7/15], Train Loss: 0.1076
Epoch [8/15], Train Loss: 0.1066
Epoch [9/15], Train Loss: 0.1057
Epoch [10/15], Train Loss: 0.1049
Epoch [11/15], Train Loss: 0.1043
Epoch [12/15], Train Loss: 0.1037
Epoch [13/15], Train Loss: 0.1032
Epoch [14/15], Train Loss: 0.1027
Epoch [15/15], Train Loss: 0.1023
Latent dim: 10, Test Loss: 0.1021
```

i notices somthing strange in the results : the test losses are smaller than the train losses , how can it happen? is somthing wrong with my model ?

i tried reading some articles about the situation :https://towardsdatascience.com/what-your-validation-loss-is-lower-than-your-training-loss-this-is-why-5e92e0b1747e

but couldn't find a good explanation for my case .
would be happy for any help .